# Get and pass Woocommerce order total into Salesforce conversion script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

In Woocommerce, I'm trying to pass the order total and convert it within Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Here's my code:

```
<?php global $woocommerce;
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
add_action('wp_head', function(){ ?>
<script src="js/salesforce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php if(!is_page(5)){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        salesforce.track();
    </script>
<?php }
if(is_page(5)){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        salesforce.conversion(5, 'order-confirmation', '<?php echo $order->get_total ?>');
    </script>
<?php }});>
```

Everything works except that the variable, `$order->get_total`, is showing up blank every time/does not convert within Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Am I using the wrong Woocommerce variable or am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you can't get the **order Id** and the `WC_Order` Object too… 
Also since Woocommerce 3+ Order properties can't be accessed directly and you need to use the available methods for `WC_Order` and `WC_Abstract_Order`…

It seems tat you are trying to get the order total in "order-received" endpoint page, so use this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'custom_saleforce_script' );
function custom_saleforce_script(){ 
    ?>
    <script src="js/salesforce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <?php 
    // For order recieved page
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) : 
        $order = wc_get_order( get_query_var('order-received') );
    ?>
        salesforce.conversion( <?php echo get_the_id() ?>, 'order-confirmation', '<?php echo $order->get_total() ?>');
    <?php 
    // For other pages
    else : ?>
        salesforce.track();
    <?php 
    endif; ?>
    </script>
    <?php 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.